# Insure the long string is uploaded to firebase reference

Tags: angularjs, base64, firebase

I'm playing with angular, firebase and base64 encoded images and now want to call some function only after i'm sure the image-string is at the reference.

For now i use Firebase .set(value, callbackFunction), but i'm not sure the callback is called when the data are uploaded to reference. Please,tell me if I'm wrong, because from what i've learned - the callback is called after firebase starts trying to send data, so if user will close the tab at this moment data will not be uploaded. Thanks!))

Answer (score 0):

I can finally state that Firebase calls set() function's callback after data are sent, so use it to prevent losing data of your user while it is uploading))))) Sorry for disturbing

Comment: Thanks for the update. The documentation for `Firebase.set()` says this about the second/`onComplete` parameter: "onComplete - A callback function that will be called when synchronization to the Firebase servers has completed. The callback will be passed an Error object on failure; else null." https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html

Comment: Yep, i've seen those docs, but due to my algorithm, could catch the moment when data are sent. Now everything works)